# common path for making directory in linux and windows

Tags: windows, linux, macos, vaadin

I have created a project in vaadin where the reports will be printed in pdf format. Everything is working as supposed but i got stuck at a point where i don't know whether my application will be deployed in linux environment or windows or Mac. I have to specify a path for making dirctory so that the report will be generated in that directory. I know how to make directory  in java but problem is can it be common path for all the O.S.
Example:
           File file=new File(path);
             if(!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
             }

I want the"path" to be common for all the O.S..
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you're going to get is `System.getProperty("user.home");`. This will give you the user's home directory, and you can stick it in a subdirectory there:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.pathSeparator + 
                       "myprogram" +  File.pathSeparator + 
                       "myFile";
File file = new File(path);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If these reports are temporary or transient (e.g. to be streamed), I would suggest simply creating a temporary file (File#createTempFile) : that way you don't have to worry about their location.